# Javascript: Присвоить значение переменной при клике на ссылку с помощью onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Есть такая конструкция:

```
<div id="wrappep">

    <div id="id1">
        <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>     
        <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
    </div>   

    <div id="id2">
        <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>     
        <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Как с помощью Javascript, либо jQuery сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку в переменную записывалось значение идентификатора блока `<div>`?

Например, при клике на `Ссылка 1` в переменную `var link` присваивается значение `id1` А при клике на `Ссылка3` `var link` будет равен `id2`

Эту нужно сделать с помощью метода onclick

```
  $('#wrapper').click(function (event) {
    // узнаем по какому элементу был клик
    // присваиваем значение по id
  })
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь функция [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```js
var link;

$('#wrappep').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
 link = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 console.log(link);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrappep">

    <div id="id1">
        <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>     
        <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
    </div>   

    <div id="id2">
        <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>     
        <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
    </div>  

</div>
```